# Change in axes(position = [...]) behavior in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Just recently, the behavior of `matplotlib` changed for me and I'm not sure why. I don't remember making any changes to my install, and many of my plotting routines have stopped working the way they used to. I'm stumped. Has anyone else come across this or have a proposed solution?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

pos1 = [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8]
pos2 = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6]

ax1 = plt.axes(position = pos1)
ax1.plot([0,1], [0, 1], color = 'r', linewidth = 3)

ax2 = plt.axes(position = pos2)
ax2.plot([1, 0], [0, 1], color = 'b', linestyle = '--')
```

The output looks like this (apologies for those who use dark mode, saving the figure with `transparent=True` helps to show what is happening):

[image: test1]

If I add these lines, then the behavior is the way I'd expect and the way it was until a few days ago:

```
ax1.set_position(pos1)
ax2.set_position(pos2)
```

[image: test2]

When I run the same code in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/), the last two lines are not necessary. I'm using `matplotlib v. 3.4.2`.

Comment: This looks to be a bug.  Please report at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib  If you know what version _used_ to work as expected, that would de very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a big thank you JodyKlymak and the matplotlib team for their [quick response](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21441#issuecomment-950192601).

As indicated on that thread, one can simply write
`ax1 = plt.axes(pos1)` and `ax2 = plt.axes(pos2)`. Also, it looks like the approach I had been using will be re-instantiated (see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/21443/commits/d8e3203e9e511ad25b3006f555e6ecd6cc4c87a0)).